# What kind of if statement is this?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

So I used an online JavaScript optimizer and it did something strange to my IF statements that is new to me.

```
{1===a?window.addEventListener("scroll",turnOff):0===a&&window.removeEventListener("scroll",turnoff)}
```

What in the world is this? Help me to understand the parts of it please.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: It's a [conditional ('ternary') operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a Conditional (Ternary) operator.

You can read more about ternary operators at the developer Mozilla docs:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

It is structured like this:

```
condition ? code if true : code if false
```

Answer (score 1):

The three equal signs are a representation of strict comparison operators. Unlike the usual double equal signs, using `===` compares both the `type` and value of the expressions being compared. Both the type and value must be equal for the statement to evaluate to true.

The `?` and `:` are shorthand versions of the `if` statement. When `1===a` is true, the statement after the question mark is evaluated. Otherwise, the statement after the colon is evaluated. This shorthand version of the `if` statement is known as a Conditional (or Ternary) operator.

Comment: Thank you, these are all great answers but yours was sorta dumb down for me XD So can you tell me the purpose of &&? why is it 0===a&& and not 0===a? ?

Comment: @Sebastian: Read a beginner's tutorial, and you'll learn all about the basic JavaScript operators.

Comment: I did :3 I know its obviously and (and) operator but what is its purpose in this statement. Andddd as I was typing this I just got it.. lmao. But to be on the safe side, its also checks if 0===1 then && is saying also do this if its found true. Otherwise neither statement is used?

Comment: Here's how it evaluates...if "1===a" is false, "0===a" will evaluated and "window.removeEventListener("scroll",turnoff)" will be invoked, which has no return value, so whatever "0===a" returns will be what is returned from the expression.

Comment: thank you, and so I tried running simple code in a test, like b.innerHTML. where b was an id element. it works in the true statement but I could only get functions to work in the second statment. why wouldnt b.innerHTML work in false but it does in true?

Answer (score 0):

The ? Operator is used just as an if.

```
if(a){
   b;
} else {
   c;
}
```

is equal to

```
a ? b : c;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's called a ternary operator. It compares the condition

`if a === 1`

and returns the first result if the condition is true:

`window.addEventListener("scroll",turnOff)`

and the second if false:

`0===a&&window.removeEventListener("scroll",turnoff)`

This line of code does two things, sets a equal to 0 and removes an event listener.

See **[this tutorial](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/conditionals-in-javascript/4/1)**